# Get records with Same "Text" but different "Code"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below (using SQL server 2008 R2 Enterprise):

```
create table Message
(
ID int Not Null Primary Key,
Text nvarchar(100) not null,
Code nvarchar(50) null
)

Insert Into Message Values (1,'Hello Everybody','T6/45')
Insert Into Message Values (2,'Hello Everybody',Null)
Insert Into Message Values (3,'Hello Everybody','T6/45')
Insert Into Message Values (4,'Hello Everybody','T6/45')
Insert Into Message Values (5,'Hello Everybody','T6/70')
Insert Into Message Values (6,'Hello Everybody','T6/70')
Insert Into Message Values (7,'Hello','T6/70')
Insert Into Message Values (8,'Hello','T6/45')
Insert Into Message Values (9,'Hello Everybody',Null)
Insert Into Message Values (10,'Hello Everybody','T6/70')
Insert Into Message Values (11,'Hello',Null)
```

I need to get all the records which are having same `Text` but different `Code`. And `Code` will not be `Null` .

So expected output will be:

```
Insert Into Message Values (1,'Hello Everybody','T6/45')
Insert Into Message Values (5,'Hello Everybody','T6/70')
Insert Into Message Values (7,'Hello','T6/70')
Insert Into Message Values (8,'Hello','T6/45')
```

I tried below query, but it is returning several rows:

```
select m1.* 
from Message M1 
With (nolock)
JOIN Message M2 
With (Nolock) 
On m1.Text=m2.Text
where (m1.ID<>m2.ID 
  and m1.Code<>m2.Code 
  and m1.Code is not null)
```

How can I get expected result?

Also, this is a sample DB. I need to run the query on a table having arount 50 Million records. So any optimized query will be of great help.

Comment: "but it is returning several rows" - what do you mean by this? Your query looks broadly right. What's it returning that you don't expect / want? Is it returning too much, too little, different records?

Comment: It is returning 20 Rows. but the expected is 4. Yes, it is returning multiple duplicate rows. Such as..   (1 Hello Everybody T6/45)
(1 Hello Everybody T6/45)
(1 Hello Everybody T6/45)
(3 Hello Everybody T6/45)
(3 Hello Everybody T6/45)
(3 Hello Everybody T6/45)

Comment: I like all the answers. +1 for everybody. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,TEXT,CODE
FROM message
WHERE ID IN 
(
  SELECT MIN(ID) FROM message
 WHERE CODE IS NOT NULL GROUP BY TEXT,CODE
)
```

or

```
SELECT 
   MIN(ID)
   ,TEXT
   ,CODE 
FROM message
WHERE CODE IS NOT NULL GROUP BY TEXT,CODE
ORDER BY MIN(ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this; [SQL-FIDDLE-DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0201/29)

```
;with cte as (
  select id,text,code, row_number() over (partition by text,code order by id) rn
  from message
  where code is not null
)
select id,text,code
from cte 
where rn = 1
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
        FROM message m2
       WHERE m2.text = m.text
         AND m2.code = m.code
         AND m2.code IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY m2.text, m2.code
      HAVING MIN(m2.id) = m.id
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.* 
FROM Message m 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM Message m1 
  WHERE m1.Id<>m.id 
  AND m1.code<>m.code 
  AND m1.Text=m.Text) 
AND m.Code IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan for the answer. But it is returning several duplicate rows.